# Check whether an element is in std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, initializer-list

I want to be able to write in C++ something similar to the following Python code:

```
if x in [1, 2, 3, 5] ...
```

to test whether an element is contained in a set of hard-coded values, defined in-place. Like this:

```
if (in(x, {1, 2, 3, 5})) ...
```

Here is the possible implementation of the `in` function:

```
template<class T>
bool in(const T& x, std::initializer_list<T> c)
{
  return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), x) != c.end();
}
```

My question is: do I really have to write this function by myself? Are there any default implementations over there? Maybe in boost? I checked `boost::contains`, but it works only with strings.

Comment: No there is nothing better in c++. But, do you really need that (convenience) python semantics in c++?

Comment: As a general rule, Python is "batteries included".... C++ is "make your own batteries from scratch".

Comment: By the way, why not omit the braces and use a variadic template? Or is that less readable?

Comment: In your question, you have an integer type and compile-time constants to check. For that, I might use `switch (x) { case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: ...; }`. It cannot be extended to support other types, or non-constant values, though.

Comment: @DieterLücking Sometimes yes, I do. It just looks awesome for me.

Comment: @Columbo Sure, I think it will be much less readable.

Comment: Please do not be reluctant to write your own algorithms. They're not that hard to write, and they can do exactly what you want them to do. And if you name them well, you can use them over and over again in your code.

Comment: @MarshallClow This is the most relevant answer so far.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have access to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can use `set`'s [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/contains) which returns a `bool` allowing you to do:

```
if(set{ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 }.contains(x))
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z7uB6CC0G7dHSZ25)

---

Otherwise, with just [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can still use `set`'s [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count) which only returns 1 or 0 allowing you to do something like:

```
if(set<int>{ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 }.count(x) > 0U)
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0BUeBfdSzBnWBgf7)

---

Keep in mind that magic numbers can be confusing for your audience (and cause 5 seasons of Lost.)
I'd recommend declaring your numbers as a `const initializer_list<int>` and giving them a meaningful name:

```
const auto finalCandidates{ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };

if(cend(finalCandidates) != find(cbegin(finalCandidates), cend(finalCandidates), x))
```

Comment: You'd better declare `foo` with `auto`.

Comment: @Mikhail is there a reason `auto` would be preferable?

Comment: Yes. The book I mentioned in the question spends the whole chapter explaining why.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not close to what I want, since the list of values itself is not inlined.

Comment: @Mikhail Maybe you can explain where declaring the variable as a `const` would be different to just inlining to a function?

Comment: Sure: it was all about verbosity and compactness in the first place. The same reason why people love C++11 custom lambdas and hate C++98 custom functors.

Comment: @Mikhail Did I miss the book you were talking about? I don't see that mentioned in here.

Comment: Hmm, trick with set is very elegant! Sorry, reference to the book was in my different question I asked recently, I confused the two. I was talking about "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers.

Comment: I somehow noticed the "Lost" joke only now, and I really with to double-up-vote now, but I can't :)

Comment: @Mikhail That was my last (of all *7*) edits to this post, so I may have put it in after you looked at it. I'm glad you enjoyed it. I chuckled at myself when I typed it in.

Answer (score 6):

`boost::algorithm::contains` doesn't only work on strings, it works on any *range*, i.e. a sequence that can yield a begin and end iterator. To find a single value use it as follows:

```
auto l = {1,2,3,4};
auto l1 = {2};      // thing you want to find
if(boost::algorithm::contains(l, l1)) { ... }
```

---

You can perform your search using the standard library only, but doing so is quite a bit more verbose. A couple of options are:

1. using a lambda

   ```
   if(std::any_of(l.begin(), l.end(), 
                  [](int i){ return i == 2; })) { ... }
   ```
2. using `std::bind`

   ```
   using std::placeholders::_1;
   if(std::any_of(l.begin(), l.end(), 
                  std::bind(std::equal_to<>(), 2, _1)) { ... }
   ```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1115c0a2ce71209c)

Note that `std::equal_to<>()` is a C++14-only option. For a C++11 compiler, use `std::equal_to<int>()`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I tried to define these ranges in place, and type deduction failed, since it cannot deduce type of `initializer_list`. That's why it cannot be used for my task directly. Sadly.

Comment: @Mikhail Yeah, unfortunately template argument deduction will not deduce an `initializer_list` from a braced-init-list. Writing a function like the one you have is the way to go if you don't want to have to create temporary `initializer_list`s. Or you can specify the type explicitly: `if(boost::algorithm::contains(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4}, std::initializer_list<int>{2}))`

Comment: put in the noexcept specifier for the lambda

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the STL does not have a simple `std::contains()` function. Recently, there was a [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/31167m/c17s_stl_what_do_you_want_it_to_have/cpxmyj1/) about this topic.

Unfortunately, what came out of this is that it is considered harmful to have `std::contains()`, since it encourages people to write slow algorithms. Think for instance of

```
if (!std::contains(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), entry)) {
    my_set.insert(entry);
}
```

This code example essentially searches for the correct position twice: Once in contains, and once to find the insert location.

In my opinion, it would still be very helpful to have `std::contains()`, but so far no one was convinced yet to write a proposal.

So either use boost (as suggested by other in this thread), or write your own function which you essentially already did :-)

Comment: I don't agree with this conclusion, but thanks for sharing!

Comment: While this is a "slow" solution, it is faster than the accepted solution that constructs a temporary set() instance and then queries that.